# How can I make ASCII send character instead of code

Tags: javascript, ascii

How can I convert `charCode` to the actual letter/digit/symbol that was typed?

I mean if `A` is typed on a keyboard the result on PHP should be the letter `A` and not the charCode for `A`.

```
var ucode = function(s) {

    var len = s.length;
    var rs = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var k = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        rs += "$" + (s.charCodeAt(i) + "1") + ";";
    }
    return rs;
};
```

Comment: ...do you mean 'key pressed true or false' instead of 'what key was pressed' ?

Comment: i want keypressed to come into myfile.php and not the code

Comment: Improved grammar / clarity of question.

Answer (score 0):

if s is string, you can use `String.prototype.slice` and change your line of code like something below

```
var ucode = function(s) {
    var len = s.length;
    var rs = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rs += s.slice(i);
    }
    return rs;
};
```

Comment: dis worked, i want it to display only the letter without adding anything including the $

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: what i mean is this. let say password is type. it keep coming in like this $success1;$uccess1;$ccess1;$cess1;$ess1;$ss1;$s1; how can i make it display just "success" which is the password without adding more string

Comment: edited the answer, is it the output you are looking for?

Comment: yes the output. this worked  "pass : johnsonohnsonhnsonnsonsononn" but the output should be pass : johnson according to what is typed on the keybboard, dont know why it keep adding more value.